# FOSRest errors formated as HTML instead of JSON

Tags: symfony, exception, fosrestbundle

My API returns HTML on error instead of JSON response.
If I rise `throw new BadRequestException('aaa');` HTML with debug and profiler is returned instead of JSON.

I use fos/rest 3.0.5

my fos_rest.yaml:

```yaml
fos_rest:
    format_listener:
        enabled: true
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: [ json, xml ], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: true }
            - { path: '^/api/doc$', priorities: [ 'text/html', '*/*' ], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
            - { path: '^/sign', priorities: [ 'text/html', '*/*' ], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
    versioning:
        enabled: true
        resolvers:
            media_type:
                enabled: true
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
        validate: true
        validation_errors_argument: validationErrors
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
            xml: true
    exception:
        enabled: false
        codes:
            'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException': 404
            'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\BadRequestHttpException': 400
            'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException': 403
            'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException': 403
            'App\Exceptions\AppException': 500
            'Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException': HTTP_CONFLICT
        messages:
            'App\Exceptions\AppException': true
    allowed_methods_listener: true
    body_listener:
        enabled: true
        default_format: json
        decoders:
            json: fos_rest.decoder.json
    param_fetcher_listener:
        enabled: true
        force: true
```

the response I get (removed rubbish):

```html
POST https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/request/017a57a0-d223-b171-beae-372f3ea6e901/786867/cs

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Allow: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 30 Jun 2021 09:59:08 GMT
X-Debug-Exception: aaa
X-Debug-Exception-File: %2Fhome%2Fjan%2Fpacketa%2Fapp%2Fzsign%2Fvendor%2Fsymfony%2Fhttp-kernel%2FHttpKernel.php:82
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<!-- aaa (400 Bad Request) -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>aaa (400 Bad Request)</title>
    <style>/* This file is based on WebProfilerBundle/Resources/views/Profiler/profiler.css.twig.
   If you make any change in this file, verify the same change is needed in the other file. */
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    document.body.classList.add(
        localStorage.getItem('symfony/profiler/theme') || (matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches ? 'theme-dark' : 'theme-light')
    );
</script>

<header>
    <div class="container">
      
</body>
</html>
<!-- aaa (400 Bad Request) -->

Response code: 400 (Bad Request); Time: 746ms; Content length: 95726 bytes
```

I would prefer to set up ErrorController but it seems not to work for 3.0 anymore.
Any idea? or example?
Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Do you have the whole request ? You should have the header Content-type: application/json

Answer (score 2):

After a long time searching for what seems a similar situation as yours, I was able to find a solution which would fix 400 errors return as json rather than html.

Simply add in:

```
fos_rest:
        exception:
                 serializer_error_renderer: true
```

This was while using JMSSerializerBundle and worked for me, hopefully it will be of use for others.